# Laravel how to filter widlcard subdomains?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-routing

Trying to filter a route based on a wild card subdomain. So basically we have a site `example.com`. I want to filter it based on some subdomains like `local.admin.example.com` and `admin.example.com`.

I have a route setup like so:

```
Route::group(['domain' => '{sub}.example.com', 'namespace' => 'Controllers\Admin'], function()
{
    Route::get('/', function(){ return Redirect::to('/dashboard'); });

    Route::any('{all}', function($uri){ return Redirect::to('/404'); })->where('all', '.*');

})->where('sub', 'local.admin');
```

When I add the `->where` it just gives me an error:

```
Call to a member function where() on a non-object
```

Basically I just wanna capture anything with `admin` in the domain and make it go to that route group. I know I could do this with some `if` statements, but seems to me cleaner to do it with a group.  Or are `if` statements the way to go here?

Answer (score 0):

You should call the `where` function on the route elements inside the group. If you only want to get a specific subdomain, you don't need to add a variable, you can just add it in the group function.

```
Route::group(['domain' => '{sub}.example.com', 'namespace' => 'Controllers\Admin'], function()
{
    Route::get('/', function(){ return Redirect::to('/dashboard'); })->where('sub', 'local.admin');
    Route::any('{all}', function($uri){ return Redirect::to('/404'); })->where('all', '.*')->where('sub', 'local.admin');
});
```

OR

```
Route::group(['domain' => 'local.admin.example.com', 'namespace' => 'Controllers\Admin'], function()
{
    Route::get('/', function(){ return Redirect::to('/dashboard'); });
    Route::any('{all}', function($uri){ return Redirect::to('/404'); })->where('all', '.*');
});
```

Comment: But then I would have to add `->where('sub', 'local.admin')` to every route in that group, seems a bit tedious.

Comment: In that case, use my second example :)

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
Route::domain('{estado}.venezuela.gob.ve')->group(function () {
  Route::get('/', 'EstadoController@index')->where('estado', 'distrito-capital|amazonas|anzoategui|apure|aragua|barinas|bolivar|carabobo|cojedes|delta-amacuro|falcon|guarico|lara|merida|miranda|monagas|nueva-esparta|portuguesa|sucre|tachira|trujillo|vargas|yaracuy|zulia|federales-federales');
  Route::get('/Otro', 'EstadoController@index')->where('estado', 'distrito-capital|amazonas|anzoategui|apure|aragua|barinas|bolivar|carabobo|cojedes|delta-amacuro|falcon|guarico|lara|merida|miranda|monagas|nueva-esparta|portuguesa|sucre|tachira|trujillo|vargas|yaracuy|zulia|federales-federales');
});

Route::domain('venezuela.gob.ve')->group(function () {
  Route::get('/', 'NacionController@index');
  Route::get('/Otro', 'NacionController@index');
});
// Another universal route
Route::get('/algo', function () {
    return "algo";
});
```

a great practice for request wildcard value maybe be it:

State Controller:

```
    namespace Venezuela\Http\Controllers;

    use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    use Venezuela\EstadosModel;

    class EstadoController extends Controller {
        public $estado;
        public $estado_actual;
        public function __construct(Request $request)
        {
            $this->estado = $request->estado;
            // Global process for all States request
            $this->estado_actual = EstadosModel::where('slug', $this->estado)->first();
        }

        public function index($estado) {
            // return view('estado.portada', ['estado' => $estado, 'estado_actual' => $this->estado_actual]);
            return 'index for: '.$estado;
        }

        public function otro($estado) {
            // return view('estado.otro', ['estado' => $estado, 'estado_actual' => $this->estado_actual]);
            return 'other action for: '.$estado;
        }

    }
```

Nation Controller:

```
    <?php

    namespace Venezuela\Http\Controllers;

    use Illuminate\Http\Request;

    class NacionController extends Controller {


        public function index() {
            // return view('nacion.portada');
            return 'index';
        }

        public function otro() {
            // return view('nacion.otro');
            return 'other action';
        }
    }
```

Result:

```
http://venezuela.gob.ve -> index
http://venezuela.gob.ve/Otro -> other action
http://venezuela.gob.ve/algo -> algo
http://lara.venezuela.gob.ve -> index for: lara
http://lara.venezuela.gob.ve/Otro -> Other for: lara
http://lara.venezuela.gob.ve/algo -> algo
http://yaracuy.venezuela.gob.ve -> index for: yaracuy
http://yaracuy.venezuela.gob.ve/Otro -> Other for: yaracuy
http://yaracuy.venezuela.gob.ve/algo -> algo
http://another.venezuela.gob.ve -> 404
http://another.venezuela.gob.ve/Otro -> 404
http://another.venezuela.gob.ve/algo -> algo
```